# How to use Github API on a ASP.NET MVC app?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, github-api

I'm new in **ASP.NET MVC** world and I've been trying to get more familiar with the .NET plataform and its particularities. Currently, I am trying to make a **C# MVC** app that uses the **Github API** to retrieve some data like list all my repositories, show some of their info, search for repositories by name (not necessarily mine) etc.
But I'm struggling on simple things. First I don't know how to make a correct connection to get these information. I've tried following the octokit tutorial on their page and tried to retrieve data using JSON and convert to a C# object but all my attempts failed on both.

I saw this example in octokit, it works for console apps:

```
var github = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("MyAmazingApp"));
var user = await github.User.Get("half-ogre");
Console.WriteLine(user.Followers + " folks love the half ogre!");
```

But I am confused where I should put these, considering the MVC structure on ASP.NET, or how it should be different. I didn't find octokit documentation very helpful on those aspects.

And some of my things I've done so far trying to deserialize JSON to C#:

**Models**

```
namespace GithubAPI.Models {
    public class Repositories {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string language { get; set; }
        public string owner { get; set; } //or login ?
        public string updated_at { get; set; }  
    }

    public class RepCollections {
        private List<Repositories> repositories;

        public List<Repositories> Repositories { get => this.repositories; set => this.repositories = value; }
    }
}
```

I did this when I tried to save JSON data to a Class

**Controllers**

```
public ActionResult Index() {
            var url = "https://api.github.com/users/{myuser}/repos";

            using (var webClient = new WebClient()) {
                var rawJSON = string.Empty;

                try {
                    rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString(url);
                }
                catch (Exception) { }

                RepCollections rep = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RepCollections>(rawJSON);

                return View();
            }
        }
```

It didn't work, probably because it's in the wrong place, idk.

**View**

```
@using GithubAPI.Models
@model RepCollections

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Repositories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Repositories</h2>
        <br/>
        <p>User: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.owner)</p>
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                <tr><th></th></tr>
                @foreach (Repositories r in Model) {
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            @r.name
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Needless to say the `foreach` didn't work.

Can someone give me some light, please? Thanks.

**P.S.: I not using OAuth. Just want a basic authentication.**

Comment: pass your model when you return your model,  return View(rep);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreach loop is not working because you are not passing the model from Controller to the View. Try this:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            var url = "https://api.github.com/users/{myuser}/repos";

            using (var webClient = new WebClient())
            {
                var rawJSON = webClient.DownloadString(url);
                RepCollections rep = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RepCollections>(rawJSON);

                return View(rep);
            }
        }
```

**View**

```
@using GithubAPI.Models
@model RepCollections

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Repositories";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <h2>Repositories</h2>
        <br />
        <p>User: @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.owner)</p>
        <div>
            <table class="table">
                <tbody>
                    <tr><th></th></tr>
                    @foreach (Repositories r in Model)
                    {
                        <tr>
                            <td>
                                @r.name
                            </td>
                        </tr>
                    }

                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello Sahil! I did what you did and I got another problem. When I tried to show the properties of my model  in @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.owner) and inside my foreach, it did not recognize the attributes. I tried to change the type to IEnumerable<> instead of List in my RepCollection class and casting the return View but again, I wasn't able to access my object properties. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is the output you get here. RepCollections rep = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RepCollections>(rawJSON); 

Can you post in your question? If it is a List, then there is no need to use IEnumerable<>.

Comment: I have updated the answer without IEnumerable<>. Check now

Comment: Still bugging :/. Now I get System.NullReferenceException on foreach line.

Comment: This is because your API call is not returning anything

Comment: haha nice. Do you know if the problem is with my url in ActionResult Index? Am I doing that correctly? It is my first time working with api and it can be a bit confusing. Thanks again.